# How to proof scalers won't matter for span of a set?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

S<sub>1</sub> = { a<sub>1</sub>v<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>v<sub>2</sub>, . . . , a<sub>n</sub>v<sub>n</sub> }

S<sub>2</sub> = { b<sub>1</sub>v<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>v<sub>2</sub>, . . . , b<sub>n</sub>v<sub>n</sub>, u }

u = c<sub>1</sub>v<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>v<sub>2</sub>, . . . , c<sub>n</sub>v<sub>n</sub>

Can I say S<sub>2</sub> = { b<sub>1</sub>v<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>v<sub>2</sub>, . . . , b<sub>n</sub>v<sub>n</sub>, c<sub>1</sub>v<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>v<sub>2</sub>, . . . , c<sub>n</sub>v<sub>n</sub> }

Therefore, S<sub>2</sub> = { (c<sub>1</sub>+b<sub>1</sub>)v<sub>1</sub>, (c<sub>2</sub>+b<sub>2</sub>)v<sub>2</sub>, . . . , (c<sub>n</sub>+b<sub>n</sub>)v<sub>n</sub> }

S<sub>2</sub> = { d<sub>1</sub>v<sub>1</sub>, d<sub>2</sub>v<sub>2</sub>, . . . , d<sub>n</sub>v<sub>n</sub> } where d<sub>i</sub> = c<sub>i</sub> + b<sub>i</sub>

Thus span (S<sub>1</sub>) = span (S<sub>2</sub>)      ?

Assume every letter has ordinary meaning.

Comment: $b_1v_1,c_1v_1$ is not the same as $b_1v_1+c_1v_1$.

Comment: Also, the awful formatting makes your question hard to read. There is help with formatting math available on this site.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you very much for your answer and I'm really sorry with the reading trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. they are equal.

(Theorem)
Suppose that,
S1 = v1,v2,....,vn
S2 = w1,w2,...,wn
If V = span{S1} and W = span{S2},
We can say both V and W spans are equal ,
Iff all the vectors in S1 is a linear combination of
vectors In S2 and all the vectors in S2 is a linear
combination of vectors in S1.

So, in your example,
All the vectors in S1 is a linear combination of vectors In S2 and all the vectors in S2 is a linear combination of vectors in S1.

aivi = 0.d1v1 + 0.d2v2+...+ (ai/di).divi...+ 0.dnvn
And
divi = 0.a1v1 + 0.a2v2 + .. + (di/ai).aivi .. + 0.dnvn

```
                    For all i = 1,2,....,n.
```